# Errors using \acrodef or \newacro

Tags: errors, acronyms

Using the package `acronym`, I get a error defining acronyms with `\acrodef` or `\newacro` instead of `\acro`:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                        
l.11 \end{acronym}
?
```

It is possible to ignore this error, but I need a compiling file for submission at a conference.

This is an example, triggering that error:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\begin{document}
This is an example; \ac{IHE}.\\
And \ac{IHE} again!

\begin{acronym}[IHE]
\acrodef{IHE}{\emph{Integrating the Health Enterprise}}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to section 2.3 of the `acronym` manual, `\acrodef` should be used "*[i]f one does not want an acronym list to be produced at all"* (p. 4). Inside an `acronym` environment simply use the `\acro` command.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\begin{document}
This is an example; \ac{IHE}.\\    And \ac{IHE} again!

\begin{acronym}[IHE]
\acro{IHE}{\emph{Integrating the Health Enterprise}}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\acrodef` works *outside* the `acronym` environment:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\acrodef{IHE}{\emph{Integrating the Health Enterprise}}
\begin{document}
This is an example; \ac{IHE}.\\    And \ac{IHE} again!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I intended not to produce the list at all.
I didn't notice that I can use `\arcodef` outside the `acronym` environment.
Looking around on this site, I found the option `nolist` for that package, too. Sadly it's not that good described in the manual; it appears in the implementation section …